# SQL Teradata - mark duplicate records in the column

Tags: duplicates, teradata

So I know how to identify a dup row but now also need to identify the row linked to it and mark as duplicate.
Ex:

```
Row     Name    ID  State   Date    Dup
---------------------------------------
001     Jim     001 NJ      jan2020 
002     Jim     001 NJ      jan2020
003     Tan     002 NY      feb2020
004     Allen   003 CA      Feb2020
```

Output should like:

```
Row     Name    ID  State   Date    Dup
---------------------------------------
001     Jim     001 NJ      jan2020 Y
002     Jim     001 NJ      jan2020 Y
003     Tan     002 NY      feb2020 N
004     Allen   003 CA      Feb2020 N
```

I can use partition using `row_number` but it will not flag the record `001` as `Y`.  What could be an approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small number of columns, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT Row, Name, ID, State, Date, 
  CASE 
    WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Name, ID, State, Date) > 1 THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N' 
  END AS Dup
FROM MyTable
```

This marks a given row as a duplicate based on the columns specified in the `PARTITION BY` expression.  Also, be careful with your column names (i.e. `Row, Date`), as they may be reserved words.

Comment: @raviolli, thanks! but the column names are only indicative and not actual names. Like I mentioned the partition will only mark row 1 as dup. I found the approach where we can simply use a subquery to get the dups and use that to mark all the records